# How can I use ExecuteScalar to check if a record exists using 2 variables such as product ID and color?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
SqlConnection BagleyData1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BagleyInvetory_VBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
BagleyData1.Open();

SqlCommand check_productSku = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[product_subtract_inventory] WHERE ([inv_prodID] = @inv_prodID) AND ([inv_color] = @inv_color)", BagleyData1);
check_productSku.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_prodID", Request.QueryString["ProdID"]);
int SkuExist = (int)check_productSku.ExecuteScalar();
BagleyData1.Close();
if (SkuExist > 0)
{
    **exists
}
else
{
   **doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you provide some explanation of the behavior of this code? Describe what is working, and what isn't working. Please provide any error message and *desired behavior* of your code in the **question post**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only major problem I see in that code is you forgot to add a line to set the value for the `@inv_color` parameter. Try adding a line like:

```
check_productSku.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_color", Request.QueryString["Color"]);
```

before you execute. Your query has two `@parameters` so your c# code should have **two** lines like `command.Parameters.AddWithValue(...)`, one for each parameter

Naturally you'll have to replace `Request.QueryString["Color"]` with the actual value you want to supply to the query

Side note; some bathroom reading material for you: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Perfect ... Thank you!

Comment: No probs. When you're bored of this laborious route of dragging data out of databases, be sure to check out http://dapper-tutorial.net :)